# Acumatica REST API - Create activity linked to customer

Tags: json, rest, acumatica, put

I am trying to programmatically add an activity to a customer entity. I can create both a customer and a note using the API with a PUT, but I cannot figure out how to relate the activity to the customer. I viewed the JSON definition using Postman, but didn't see anything that made sense for relating it to another entity. I tried adding RelatedEntityDescription, but that unsurprisingly did not work.

Here is my JSON body for the PUT (it works but creates an un-linked activity)

```
{ 
  "Body": {
    "value": "message text"
   },
  "Date": {
    "value": "2020-04-22T15:28:00.99-05:00"
  },
  "Summary": {
    "value": "Test message"
  }  
}
```

What do I need to add to link it to my customer?

Answer (score 0):

Good day Sreimer

The Table you should be saving to is Note.

It links on BAccount.NoteID and Note.NoteID.

An easy way to test this is to create and save a note on a customers and look for it in Note:

```
select * 
from Note
where NoteText like '%test%';
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify the `RelatedEntityType` and `RelatedEntityNoteID` in your request

```
{
    "Body": {},
    "Date": {
        "value": "2021-01-06T14:42:03.837-08:00"
    },
    "RelatedEntityNoteID": {
        "value": "01a0c017-df7f-ea11-8175-b9d61cb73193"
    },
    "RelatedEntityType": {
        "value": "PX.Objects.AR.Customer"
    },
    "Summary": {
        "value": "Test Activity 4"
    },
    "Type" : {
        "value" : "M"
    }
}
```